# How to prevent android SearchView Query toggling while text is typing

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, searchview

I got my view with SearchView component. The problem is every new symbol in the input field toggling `Query` action, so there are some `http` request are fire etc, so it starts to working slow.

I want it to run only after I click on search button on virtual keyboard (bellow button ).

[image]

Is there any properties for that in `SearchView`?

**layout code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        local:MvxBind="Query SearchString" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Or I should make something like custom binding which detects keyboard key click?

**UPD:**

Some code to make clear part of how search works:

View model

```
public class RemoteMusicSearchViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private IMvxNavigationService _mvxNavigationService;
        private IRemoteMusicDataService _remoteMusicDataService;
        private int _currentPage;

        public RemoteMusicSearchViewModel(IMvxNavigationService mvxNavigationService,
            IRemoteMusicDataService remoteMusicDataService)
        {
            _mvxNavigationService = mvxNavigationService;
            _remoteMusicDataService = remoteMusicDataService;
        }

        public override void Start()
        {
            base.Start();

            _currentPage = 0;
        }

        private string _searchString;

        public string SearchString
        {
            get { return _searchString; }

            set
            {
                _searchString = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchString);
                PerformBasicSearch().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<DownloadableEntity> _foundItems;

        public ObservableCollection<DownloadableEntity> FoundItems
        {
            get { return _foundItems; }

            set
            {
                if (_currentPage > 0)
                {
                    _foundItems = new ObservableCollection<DownloadableEntity>(_foundItems.Concat(value));
                }
                else
                {
                    _foundItems = value;
                }

                RaisePropertyChanged(() => FoundItems);
            }
        }

        private async Task PerformBasicSearch(int page = 0)
        {
            string request = SearchString;
            string result = await _remoteMusicDataService.SearchByProperty(request, MusicSearchType.ByTracks, page).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var searchResult = MusicSearchResult.FromJson(result);

            await PrepareDataForOutput(searchResult).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

full layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        local:MvxBind="Query SearchString"
        />

    <MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/searchlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FoundItems"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the part, that you are spawning a request?

Comment: @azizbekian I'll update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - I just created new binding for that:

```
public class SearchViewKeyPressEventsBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
    {
        private readonly SearchView _searchView;
        private IMvxAsyncCommand _command;

        public SearchViewKeyPressEventsBinding(SearchView searchView) : base(searchView)
        {
            _searchView = searchView;
            _searchView.QueryTextSubmit += _searchView_KeyPress;
        }

        private void _searchView_KeyPress(object sender, SearchView.QueryTextSubmitEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_command != null)
                {
                    _command.ExecuteAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public override Type TargetType
        {
            get { return typeof(IMvxAsyncCommand); }
        }


        protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
        {
            try
            {
                _command = (IMvxAsyncCommand)value;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("SOME BINDER FAIL\n\t" + e.Message + "\n", "SOME BINDER FAIL\n\t" + e.Message + "\n");
                throw;
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                _searchView.QueryTextSubmit -= _searchView_KeyPress;
            }
            base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Then registred it and it worked:

```
   registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<SearchView>("OnSearchSubmit", (sv) => new SearchViewKeyPressEventsBinding(sv)))
```

In layout:

```
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        local:MvxBind="Query SearchString; OnSearchSubmit OnSubmitPressCommand" />
```

And don't forget to set up viewmodel's property:

```
 public IMvxAsyncCommand OnSubmitPressCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxAsyncCommand(OnSearchSubmit);
            }
        }

  private async Task OnSearchSubmit()
        {
            //HideKeyboardOnSearchStart.Invoke(this, null);
            await PerformBasicSearch().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are looking for a manual solution for the problem.

With each key event you get you can fire a delayed action after a certain threshold 500 milliseconds for example.

Maybe using `Handler.postDelayed()`

Then there three scenarios

- Another event comes before that fires, so you call `Handler.removeCallbacks()` and fire another delayed action
- Another event comes while the request is already fired, but no result yet, so you cancel the request and fire your delayed action.
- An event comes while no delayed action pending or request pending, so you just fire a delayed action.

However, if you are willing to use any Reactive variant, there are more sophisticated solutions for that, by basically debouncing the events of keyboard strokes.

Comment: Well I just want to prevent run query till button would be pressed